# Test a zoom of d3js with cypress

Tags: testing, d3.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm testing a chart made with d3.js. This graph zooms in by scrolling on it.
I would like with cypress to trigger the zoom with the scroll, I have made these attempts but nothing happens.

```
 cy.get('.pippo > svg')
  .trigger('wheel', 500, 500, { force: true });


 cy.get('.pippo > svg')
  .trigger('wheel', { x: 500, y: 500, force: true });
```